# C# Compiler Extension doesn't show messages on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions

I have a `DiagnosticAnalyzer` subclass that correctly identifies my issues, and shows them in the Errors window in VS. Writing the code fix is next, but I don't foresee any problems with that.

However, when I actually build my application, the warnings and errors I added do not show up. Is this a limitation of diagnostic analyzers? If not, how can I inform  Roslyn that I want to see these problems at build time too?

Comment: Are you using your analyzer as a Visual Studio extension or as a NuGet package?

Comment: I'll use it as a Nuget package in the end, but to debug I'm running the vsix extension. Are you saying it would show up when it's used from a Nuget library?

Comment: Yes! Visual Studio extensions run only on Visual Studio. I never use analyzers/fixers as VS extensions because of that.

Comment: @Blindy Hi, any update for this issue? Please check if Paulo's answer(use it as nuget package) helps to resolve this issue, you can consider marking it as answer if it helps. Just a reminder:)

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019#nuget-package-versus-vsix-extension):

> Roslyn code analyzers can be installed per-project via a NuGet package. Some are also available as a Visual Studio extension, in which case they apply to any solution you open in Visual Studio. There are some key behavior differences between these two methods of installing analyzers.
>
> #### Scope
>
> If you install analyzers as a Visual Studio extension, they apply at the solution level and to all instances of Visual Studio. If you install the analyzers as a NuGet package, which is the preferred method, they apply only to the project where the NuGet package was installed. In team environments, analyzers installed as NuGet packages are in scope for all developers that work on that project.
>
> #### Build errors
>
> To have rules enforced at build time, including through the command line or as part of a continuous integration (CI) build, install the analyzers as a NuGet package. Analyzer warnings and errors don't show up in the build report if you install the analyzers as an extension.